# Mutate JavaScript Array Inside Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, how do I mutate the value of an array inside of a function? I know that happens when using certain array methods, but it doesn't seem to work for normal assignment.

```
var arr = [4]

function changeArray(arr) {
arr = [1,2,3];
}

// arr is still equal to [4]. I want it to equal [1,2,3].
```

It's my understanding that this code doesn't change the value of "arr" outside of the function. How can I do it in a way that mutates the array that was passed as an argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
arr.splice(0, arr.length, 1, 2, 3);
```

Or you can empty the array and `.push` the values:

```
arr.length = 0;
arr.push(1, 2, 3);
// or given an array of values
arr.push.apply(arr, newValues);
```

However, make sure it is clear that the function changes the array *in place*. While there are native functions that does this (like `Array#sort`), I'd argue that this is not as common as simply returning a new array.

---

> It's my understanding that this code doesn't change the value of "arr" outside of the function.

Correct. Assigning a new value to a variable or property **never** changes the value of another variable or property (exceptions: global scope and `with` statements).
You basically tried to change the value of a variable, not mutate the value itself.

JavaScript is call/pass/assign [**by *value***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value#Call_by_value) (Wikipedia also mentions ["by sharing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value#Call_by_sharing)), not [by *reference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_reference#Call_by_reference).

Comment: The concat method does not mutate the original array. Therefore, if you want to mutate an array by adding another array inside a function, you need to use a combination of a loop and push/splice?

Comment: If you simply want to add multiple elements from an array, you can use `.push` + `.apply`: `arr.push.apply(arr, newElements);`